# Test Case for typeof window undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How can we test else case for window. In My test cases it checks the if statement. But coverage shows else part not taken. How can we test that.

```
function sample(){
  if(typeof window !== undefined){
    doSomething()
  }
}
```

Comment: With `window`, what are you going to do? Why you want to check window for `undefined`?

Comment: Just add an `else` and put something inside like `console.log` :-)

Comment: @Thaadikkaaran they are assigning some property to window . For that I have to create test cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/* istanbul ignore else */` to ignore the else part coverage.

For your case,

```
function sample(){
  /* istanbul ignore else */
  if(typeof window !== undefined){
    doSomething()
  }
}
```

Check [here](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/lib/config.js#L14) for the other options.

Comment: Thanks for your support :)